# Importing CAD to ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, cad, microstation

I'm trying to import some CAD files from microstation (dgn) v7 to ArcGis 9.3.1 and i need to access the User Data Linkage from it but i have not the Data Interoperability License.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Import From CAD Conversion Tool in ArcToolbox (does not require interoperability extension)

"The Input files parameter will allow the addition of different kinds of CAD data (DGN, DWG, DXF) in one operation."

Go to the tool help for more details on Microstation projection, post-processing for joins and or data relationships, etc.

Alternatively, you could try something like this: http://mygeodata.eu/apps/converter/index_EN.html#convertVector

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), the vector counterpart to [GDAL](https://gdal.org/). You will have to georeference it yourself though. If you'd prefer a GUI, you could also try [ogr2gui](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621022036/http://www.ogr2gui.ca/en/index.php). Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you can export your dgn file to dwg or dxf, arcmap can easily show them.
All you'll have to do is set an spatial reference (projection file .prj) to your file in ArcCatalog and then add the kind of vector you want (polygon, polyline, points) to the Table of Contents.

You can do this with any ArcGIS license.